# How do I know what height/width to set for CSS?

Tags: html, css, height, width

I don't fully understand how to determine rem, em, px, or %.

I know what each one means, but it's still unclear to me to know *when* to use each one. What are the criteria for knowing which ones to use?

Your input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The units `cm`, `px`, `pt` etc are known as absolute length units and are used for exact sizes and would not change based on many factors like screen size. Units like `vw`, `vh`, `%` etc are known as relative size units and change based on the size of the screen you are viewing the page on.

Comment: Why would em, which is related to font size, change with screen size?

Comment: @AHaworth I wasn't thinking. I fixed it.

Comment: i get it now. thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Pixels `px`, points `pt` etc are considered as absolute units. Good place to use pixel definition is when you want some element maintain consistent sizing i.e. the element should not be resized. E.g. icons, certain images or layout decorations could be defined using `px`.

On the other hand `em`, `rem`, `%`, `vw`, `vh` etc are relative units and better fit for responsive design. Relative units are calculated from the base sizes. Difference between `em` and `rem` is that `em` is based on the parent element whereas `rem` is based on the root element. These are good for font sizing, e.g. if the user defines their browser base font to 14px (normally 16px is the default size), the website fonts using `em` / `rem` would adjust to its users wishes but `px` would not do so.

Percent definition `%` is commonly used in layout elements where the overall layout is broken down into percent sized columns. These columns will adjust when the screen size changes, and alongside media queries these column percentages can be thereby adjusted based on screen size.

From my personal point of view viewport width `vw` and viewport height `vh` are less used but useful when you need to layout something according to actual viewport size. E.g. creating 2 colored or layered background could be one use case for this.

Comment: thank you so much for the thorough response! this helped a lot.